# How to properly use async/await func?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

I'm working on node.js server with express. I processing a `POST` request like this:

```
app.post('/signup', async (req, res) => {
    let user = {
        email: req.body.userEmail,
        pass: req.body.userPass
    }
    try {
        let insertedUser = await User.create(user)
        console.log(insertedUser.get('email'))
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(`ERROR! => ${err.message}`)
    }
})
```

To make it work I have to put `async` before callback function. But why do I have to do it if `app.post()` is already async function?

Do I work with async/await right?

Comment: "*`app.post()` is already async function*" - no, it's not, it doesn't return a promise? What made you think it is written as an `async function`? And why would that even matter for the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are working correctly (except for the fact that you aren't using `res` to respond to the request).

The reason you need to use `async` is that the signature of `app.post()` is

```
app.post(path: string, handler: (req: Request, res: Response) => void): void
```

that is, two parameters, one a path which is a string, and the handler, which is a function that accepts the two parameters (it accepts more, but for the sake of simplicity, let's ignore those for now), and returns nothing.

As you can see, `app.post()` onto itself has no interesting return value (and especially, it does not return a Promise), so it isn't an async function on its own.

You are passing a function, describing what you want to be done when a request hits the path (`'/signup'`, in your case). Since you want to use async features (a.k.a. `await`) in that function, that function must be marked `async`.

---

TL;DR - Your handler function is async, `app.post()` is not.

Answer (score 1):

This `async/await` has nothing to do with `app.post()` being async as async/await is a feature introduced ES5+ to handle Asynchronous calls with in the functions in synchronous way. Think of it like extended version of Promises, just it looks like Synchronous, but does the same thing. So your code looks correct to me.